# Spring Reactive : Service method call is not able to return response

Tags: spring, java-8, reactive-programming, spring-webflux, spring-reactive

Trying to rewrite a working reactive function by including a small validation in between.
Unfortunately, the program is not able to complete the request even though the computation is completed in the backend.
Also, It will be great if someone can tell me if there is any unnecessary coding practice related to reactive.

1. Handler function, from where we invoke the reactive service

   ```
       public Mono<ServerResponse> performValidation(ServerRequest serverRequest) {
       Mono<Request> request = serverRequest.bodyToMono(Request.class);
       return ServerResponse.ok()
               .body(service1.performValidation(boundaryCheckRequest, ""), ServiceResponse.class)
               //.body(service1.performValidation_Working(boundaryCheckRequest, ""), ServiceResponse.class)
               .onErrorResume(Exception.class,
                       e -> ServerResponse.status(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
                               .body(Mono.just(e.getMessage()), String.class));}
   ```
2. Handler invokes the below service, the below code snippet is having issue

   ```
   public Mono<ServiceResponse> performValidation(Mono<ServiceRequest> requestMono,String token) {
       return Mono.create(monoSink -> {
           requestMono.map(triggerRequest -> {
               return checkValidOrders(triggerRequest)?doValidations(requestMono,token).subscribe():Mono.just(new ServiceResponse()).subscribe();
           }).subscribe();
       });
   }

   private Mono<ServiceResponse> doValidations(ServiceRequest request,String token){
       RequestHolder requestHolder= new RequestHolder(request,token);
       ServiceResponseObject serviceBus=new ServiceResponseObject();
       return Mono.create(monoSink -> {
           Flux.merge(
                   getServiceOne(requestHolder, serviceBus),
                   getServiceTwo(requestHolder, serviceBus)
                 )
                   .doOnNext(completedFlag -> {
                   })
                   .doOnComplete(() -> {
                       ServiceResponse ServiceResponse = validationService.validate(serviceBus, requestHolder.getRequest());
                       monoSink.success(ServiceResponse);
                   })
                   .doOnError(throwable -> {
                       monoSink.success(handleError(throwable, requestHolder));
                   })
                   .subscribe();
       });
   }
     private Boolean checkValidOrders(ServiceRequest tr){
       return tr.getLines().stream().anyMatch(line-> !line.getStatus().equals("ACIVE"));
   }
   ```
3. working version of the service code.

```
    public Mono<ServiceResponse> performValidation_Working(Mono<ServiceRequest> requestMono,String token) {
        return Mono.create(monoSink -> {
            requestMono.map((triggerReq)->
            {
                return new RequestHolder(request,token);
            })
            .subscribe(servicesRequestHolder -> {
                ServiceResponseObject serviceBus=new ServiceResponseObject();
                Flux.merge(
                        getServiceOne(requestHolder, serviceBus),
                        getServiceTwo(requestHolder, serviceBus)
                )
                    .doOnNext(completedFlag -> { })
                    .doOnComplete(()->{
                        ServiceResponse ServiceResponse = validationService.validate(serviceBus, requestHolder.getRequest());
                        monoSink.success(ServiceResponse);
                    })
                    .doOnError(throwable -> {
                        monoSink.success(handleError(throwable,servicesRequestHolder));
                    })
                    .subscribe();
            });
        });
    }
```

Not able to figure out why the request processing is not ending, kindly advise.

Comment: I can see you call subscribe, you should not do that. Let spring subscribe to the top Mono/Flux and chain - read flat map following steps.

`request.flatMap(request -> service1.performValidation(request, "")).flatMap(validatedRequest-> ...`

Comment: okey, this is one of the messiest, reactive code examples i have ever seen. I have so many questions. What is `getServiceOne` and what is `getServiceTwo` can you please explain on a high level, you get a request, you want to validate that the request has some lines that say active, and then?

Comment: what is `validationService.validate` and why all the subscribing?

Comment: @Thomas Andolf, Thanks a lot for your kind response. I have just started with reactive and so kindly excuse :) . getServiceOne and two is invoked to get data from two external services(Flux.merge is used to gather all the required data before proceeding to validation service)  which is required  by the validationService to complete the validations. Thanks.